# Grouping repeated data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window

using SQl2008 R2. I have a large set of records (100k) that are sorted by a specific order (I used ID in my sample data). I must maintain this sequence

I want to increment the group whenever a set fields change. I thought it would be easy with window functions, but I'm stuck

My data is

```
ID  Letter  Number
1      A       1
2      B       2
3      B       2
4      B       2
5      A       1
```

Result required is

```
ID  Letter  Number  GroupID
1      A       1       1
2      B       2       2
3      B       2       2
4      B       2       2
5      A       1       3
```

Basically when the combination of Col1 and Col2 changes WHEN SORTED, I want to increment the groupno. i.e. Even though row 1 and 5 both contain A 1, they must have unique GroupNos because they are interupted by 2,3,4

(My real data contains several fields that need to be compared)

```
 -- Create tables to work with / Source and Destination
CREATE TABLE #Items
    (
     ID INT 
    ,Letter VARCHAR(1)
    ,Number INT
    )

CREATE TABLE #Results
    (
     ID INT 
    ,Letter VARCHAR(1)
    ,Number INT
    ,GroupID int
    )


INSERT INTO #Items
        ( ID,Letter, Number )
SELECT 1, 'A', 1
UNION
SELECT 2, 'B', 2
UNION
SELECT 3,'B', 2
UNION
SELECT 4, 'B', 2
UNION
SELECT 5, 'A', 1

SELECT * FROM #Items
ORDER BY ID

INSERT INTO #Results
        ( ID,Letter, Number, GroupID )
SELECT 1, 'A', 1, 1
UNION
SELECT 2, 'B', 2,2
UNION
SELECT 3,'B', 2,2
UNION
SELECT 4, 'B', 2,2
UNION
SELECT 5, 'A', 1,3
```

Thanks in advance

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to solve this problem is as the difference of two row numbers.  This uniquely identifies each sequence of values.  Then use `dense_rank()`.  Here is the query:

```
select ID, Letter, Number,
       dense_rank() over (order by diff, letter) as GroupId
from (select i.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by letter order by id)
             ) as diff
      from #items i
     ) t
```

Given your data, here is what the row numbers, differences, and final value look like:

```
ID  Letter  Number   RN-ID  RN-Letter  Diff   GroupId
1      A       1       1       1         0       1
2      B       2       2       1         1       2
3      B       2       3       2         1       2
4      B       2       4       3         1       2
5      A       1       5       2         3       3
```

Voila!  Almost like magic.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3224/2) is the example on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression with a self join to emulate SQL Server 2012's `LAG` and detect the changes. The reason for the cte is to make sure that the row numbers are consecutive since `id` may not be;

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn FROM #items )
SELECT a.id, a.letter, a.number, 
  1 + SUM(CASE WHEN a.letter<>b.letter OR a.number<>b.number THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      OVER (ORDER BY a.id) groupid
FROM cte a LEFT JOIN cte b ON a.rn = b.rn + 1
ORDER BY a.id
```

SQLfiddle is a bit tired right now, so can't add one. This is tested on SQL Server 2012, but *should* work on 2008R2.

Comment: thanks guys. both worked. i chose the first option as it fit with my overall query a bit better